# trying to change default icon in tkinter Tk() at the top of the "window"

Tags: python, tkinter, filepath, .ico

Not sure why I'm  getting an error I followed like 6 guides to make a .ico file and literally copied
two tutorials trying all types of combinations of relative non relative file path

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = Tk()
root.title('Local Host Store')
root.geometry("500x500")

root.iconbitmap('pleasegod1.ico')

#mainloop

root.mainloop()

                        <ERROR CODE BELOW>
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Eric\Desktop\LocalHostStore\main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Eric\Desktop\LocalHostStore\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap('pleasegod1.ico')
  File "C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2071, in 
wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "pleasegod1.ico" not defined
```

Comment: What is your project structure exactly?

Comment: Execute `print(os.getcwd())` (need `import os`) before `root.iconbitmap(...)` and see whether the expected path is printed in console.

Comment: try providing the whole path

Comment: make a new file in the same dir and `import os` after that `os.startfile('pleasegod1.ico')`, see if python can open up the file. Also try giving it a full path. You can also check if the file exists by saying `print(os.path.exists('pleasegod1.ico'))`

Comment: same file opens in html xD java program useable as photo in tkinter widgets seriously just not worth my time at this point :/

Comment: Then you either put your alternate solution as an answer and close this question, or delete this question.

Comment: try adding your file path, like what @acw1668 said, using `os.getwd()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to type the entire image path or place the image in the same code file and make sure that the image type is .ico

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution is to use `Tk.iconphoto()` method and not `Tk.iconbitmap()`. Instead `root.iconphoto(True,PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/GuiFlowerIcon.png"))` worked fine, it's just not using a .icon file I suppose. Not efficient to trouble shoot `Tk.iconbitmap()` for my use case.     this just changes the icon at the top of the tkinter window from the default tkinter library "trademark" icon to a custom one of your own. iconphoto can be png.

Side note: I went through great lengths to follow tutorials to create .ico file, my file was 15x15 px grid in ms paint saved as bitmap 24 I think and then converted file type to .ico and windows recognized it as such, wheras if you try to change big png file to .ico it won't let you actually even change the file extension... super odd.

The problem still may be it doesn't recognize it as .ICO file if anyone have any tips to make a .ico file that python tkinter can recognize or how it even goes about this in.. c language? behind the scenes that would be super cool as I hope to unpack tkinter one day and how it works under the hood.